# How does angular deal with two similar routes that have different parameters?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular-routing

How does angular deal with two similar routes that have different parameters?

For example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':username',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':username2',
    component: HomeComponent2
  }
];
```

How does angular know or how do you tell angular which parameter is `username` and which parameter is `username2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot, it will always go to `UserComponent`, as that's the first match it will find. They should always have a identifiable path part:

```
{
  path: 'user/:username',
  component: UserComponent
},
{
  path: 'home/:username2',
  component: HomeComponent2
}
```